# how to deal with Unsatisified Link Error in Linux?

Tags: java, linux, shared-libraries, unsatisfiedlinkerror

Am loading one of the .so file in my java application which is running in Linux box. Am getting 'unsatisfied Link error not able to load' error even though I am giving correct path. Can anyone explain me the problem?
Thank in advance..!!

Comment: Please post the Java code, stack trace, and output of `java -version` and `file mylib.so`.

Comment: which library it is complaining?

Comment: Am loading third party library in my java file. This is working fine when i run it in JDeveloper where I used to give it in VM Arguments. But after deploying in orion server its not able to load that library even though I am giving correct path. I shouldn't be sharing code as it is not allowed. Thanks..!!

Comment: @Alexander Could you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: @SMA it's a third party library.

Comment: Do you have that library path in LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable?

Comment: @vkreddy: `ls -l <pathToLib>` This should output something like ` -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     root         9968 Nov 22  2013 /usr/libexec/sudo_noexec.so` whereas `rwxr-xr-x` means Read,Write and eXecute for *owner* (root), Read and eXecute for *group* and *world*. If you java process is owned by neither user nor group, *world* rules are applied

Comment: @SMA Yeah.. but I have to do something like this... -Dm.abc.lib = /abc/def/test.so   How can I set it in LD_LIBRARY_PATH... Thanks..!!

Comment: @Alexander  It has all the permissions.. RWX

Answer (score 0):

Add library path where .so resides in LD_LIBRARY_PATH like:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/mypath/lib
```

OR

when starting JVM pass JVM argument as:

```
-Djava.library.path=/mypath/lib
```

Comment: Thanks @SMA.. I have done this. It is able to find the file. But it is throwing error 'Unsatisfied link error  not able to load lib.so file'

Comment: what all commands you executed? Also send output of ls -l for each path that you added in path.